# Record to a pulseaudio stream, and manage switching between streams

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio

I am trying to set up audio card configurations along with pulseaudio, but I am not sure how alsa configuration is exactly done.

Until this point, I was able to use a single card, and select default source and sink as follows, that worked until I needed to mix another stream to my output.

```
pacmd set-default-source alsa_input.platform-sound.analog-mono
pacmd set-default-sink alsa_output.platform-sound.analog-mono
```

Now, I am going to use one more sound card, so aplay -l gives:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: cs42888audio [cs42888-audio], device 0: HiFi cs42888-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: wm8960audio [wm8960-audio], device 0: HiFi wm8960-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: wm8960audio [wm8960-audio], device 1: HiFi-ASRC-FE (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: amixaudiosai [amix-audio-sai], device 0: HiFi-AMIX-FE (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: amixaudiosai [amix-audio-sai], device 1: HiFi-AMIX-FE (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

arecord -l gives:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: cs42888audio [cs42888-audio], device 0: HiFi cs42888-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: wm8960audio [wm8960-audio], device 0: HiFi wm8960-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: wm8960audio [wm8960-audio], device 1: HiFi-ASRC-FE (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: amixaudiosai [amix-audio-sai], device 0: HiFi-AMIX-FE (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

pactl list short sinks

```
0   alsa_output.platform-sound-amix-sai.analog-mono module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
2   alsa_output.platform-sound.analog-mono  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
4   alsa_output.platform-sound-cs42888.analog-surround-51   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 6ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
5   my_stream   module-null-sink.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

pactl list short sources

```
0   alsa_output.platform-sound-amix-sai.analog-mono.monitor module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_input.platform-sound-amix-sai.analog-mono  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
3   alsa_input.platform-sound-cs42888.analog-mono   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
4   alsa_output.platform-sound.analog-mono.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
5   alsa_input.platform-sound.analog-mono   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 1ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
7   alsa_output.platform-sound-cs42888.analog-surround-51.monitor   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 6ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
8   my_stream.monitor   module-null-sink.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

I would like to use CS42888 device and set up a configuration such as the following:

```
alsa_input.platform-sound-cs42888.analog-mono (Radio)
(Rate 48000, S16_LE)
|
>    alsa_input.platform-sound.analog-mono (Microphone)
|          |
|          >    alsa_input.a2dp_source (Bluetooth Audio, if available)
|          |         |
|          |         |   
|          |         |      System sounds
|          |         |            |
|          |         |            >
|          |         |            |
|          |         >            |
|          |         |            |
-----------switching stream--------
     |
     |
     >
     |
     |
alsa_output.platform-sound-cs42888.analog-mono
(Rate 48000, S16_LE)
(profile: output:analog-mono+input:analog-mono)
```

In other words, I would like to get Radio input, and be able to stream it on top of system sounds, whenever necessary. Also, I would like to achieve this in pulseaudio, since bluetooth audio and other stuff are managed using pulseaudio (module-bluez5-device).

I can get record and play radio input as follows successfully:

```
arecord -Dplug:hw:cs42888audio -f S16_LE -r 48000 test.wav
aplay -Dplug:hw:cs42888audio -f S16_LE test.wav
```

How do I set up such a configuration using pulseaudio? I would like to record to a stream and then manage switching between streams. Thanks in advance.